# FAQ dropdown- Text color changed when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a JavaScript dropdown for my FAQ, and what I can't figure out is how to have the color of the question change when clicked, and then change back when clicked again.

Here's the JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle(Info) {
var CState = document.getElementById(Info);
CState.style.display = (CState.style.display != 'block')
                   ? 'block' : 'none';}
</script>
```

I know using :action will work just for when the question is clicked, but I'm trying to style it so that each click either turns the color on or off, as that's what happens with the answer dropping down and I'd like both to be coordinated.

Comment: And what HTML does this act on? What is 'Info'?

Comment: How are you triggering this toggle? Can you create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) please?

Comment: So add a class to the element that was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you toggle function shows/hides the answer. Then all you have to do is to get the question container and toggle a css class which contains the text color

For example:

```
document.getElementById(your question).classList.toggle(your-class);
```

and in a css file

```
.your-class {
    color: selected color;
}
```

Comment: Note that `classList` is not avail in IE9. Use jQuery or a shim for full support.

Comment: I'm not great with JQuery.. can you clarify where I have to add this, and how I set the colors?

Comment: jquery has a method .toggleClass() which does exactly this. you would have to add jquery to your page and instead of doing document.getElementById, you would ĵust do $('#your question').toggleClass('your class'). And you set the colors in your css class. .your-class{ color: selected color;}

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.classStyle1 {background-color:white}
.classStyle2 {background-color:green}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle(Info) {
var CState = document.getElementById(Info);

if(CStage.className == "classStyle1"){
     CStage.className = classStyle2;
}else{
     CStage.className = classStyle1;
}
// or else
// create style attribute for select element and put style='background-color:white' like this 
if(CStage.style.backgroundColor == "white"){
     CStage.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
}else{
     CStage.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly - try this
`CState=document.getElementById("myColor");
CState.onmouseover=function(){this.style.color='red';};
CState.onmouseout=function(){this.style.color='blue';};`